# Parse a csv file, replace separator, ignoring the content of fields between " "

Tags: text-processing, csv, replace

I have a file with `;` separators ; my application parses the data, based on those separators. String fields are between `""` and in columns, I might have the separator as text.
I would like to replace the separator in that file ( for example changing it to `|`) ignoring the values between `""`. An example follows:

Input:

> `"BARCELONA";"";"Country.666;53;98";15;19;"test";4343;63647;655848`

OUTPUT

> `"BARCELONA"|""|"Country.666;53;98"|15|19|"test"|4343|63647|655848`

Answer (score 3):

To get your precise output,

```
$ perl -MText::CSV -lpe '
    BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new({sep_char => ";"})} 
    $_ = join "|", map { /^\d+$/ ? $_ : qq("$_") } $p->fields() if $p->parse($_)
  ' INPUT
"BARCELONA"|""|"Country.666;53;98"|15|19|"test"|4343|63647|655848
```

If you don't insist on the unconventional quoting, then

```
$ csvformat -d';' -D'|' INPUT
BARCELONA||Country.666;53;98|15|19|test|4343|63647|655848
```

Forcing quote non-numeric for both input and output *almost* works the way you want (but apparently promotes the numeric fields to floating-point):

```
$ csvformat -d';' -u2 -D'|' -U2 INPUT
"BARCELONA"|""|"Country.666;53;98"|15.0|19.0|"test"|4343.0|63647.0|655848.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing data in fields is not safe.

For parsing csv files, you could use `csvtool`

```
$ echo '"BARCELONA";"";"Country.666;53";15' | csvtool -t ';' col 1- -
BARCELONA,,Country.666;53,15
```

or for particular fields

```
$ echo '"BARCELONA";"";"Country.666;53";15' | csvtool -t ';' col 1,3 -
BARCELONA,Country.666;53
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be easy to do it with `awk`, but it ended up becoming a bit of a mess. However, since I went through the effort of solving it, here is a potential solution with `awk` that takes advantage of the `FPAT` feature:

```
cat file.txt | awk -v FPAT='[^;]+|"[^"]+"' '{ for( col=1; col<=NF; col++ ) { printf "%s|", $col; } print "" }'
```

Basically, it uses the `FPAT` regex to define what is classified as a item (either no semicolon or quotes), and reprint them with a (`|`) character between columns. Originally, I wanted to use the `OFS` option, but it looks like it doesn't play well with the `FPAT` option

Comment: It is not working. echo '"BARCELONA";"";"Country.666;53";15' | awk -v FPAT='[^;]+|"[^"]+"' '{ for( col=1; col<=NF; col++ ) { printf "%s|", $col; } print "" }'
"BARCELONA";"";"Country.666;53";15|

Comment: @Jason K Lai The `cat someFile | awk <awkCommands>` construct is a useless use of `cat`. `awk <awkCommands> someFile` is enough.

Comment: I really like this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `GNU sed` editor with extended regexes enabled:

```
$ sed -Ee 's/(("[^"]*")+|[^;]+);/\1|/g' in.csv
```